# Tomcat 6: HTTPS times out but HTTP works (Maybe GWT issue?)

Tags: gwt, tomcat, https

We have a Linux server running tomcat6  (6.0.36).  We have a GWT-based web-app.  It has been running fine for 2 years, until twice in 5 days it developed a problem:  HTTPS ceased to work even though HTTP works fine.  Both times, a simple restart solved the problem.

- The certificates are not close to expiry and indeed are fine after the restart
- There was no significant load on the server at the time of the fault, CPU and %MEM were fine
- HTTP responds instantly
- HTTPS just times out without giving us any clues
- There's nothing in the 'catalina.out' file but there are SocketTimeoutException's in the localhost.*log file, see below
- A thread dump (kill -3) shows nothing out of the ordinary

Any ideas, anyone?

```
SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprInputBuffer.fill(InternalAprInputBuffer.java:796)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalAprInputBuffer.java:830)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprInputBuffer.doRead(InternalAprInputBuffer.java:738)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:304)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:419)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:327)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:162)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCServletUtils.readContent(RPCServletUtils.java:222)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCServletUtils.readContentAsGwtRpc(RPCServletUtils.java:250)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.readContent(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:182)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:239)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at au.com.edval.timetable.server.filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:27)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:600)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1703)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Jul 30, 2013 10:27:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
```

Note that a couple of years ago I had a similar problem - HTTPS was working but was very slow.  It turns out there was a configuration option that says that HTTPS should do reverse DNS lookups on each page request.  And this naturally slowed everything down heaps. But this is still disabled now so it can't be the cause, I don't think.

Comment: Can you dump the portion of the log which is relevant to responding to HTTPS request here?

Comment: What's the minor version?  Did you check the changelog to see if a bug was fixed? http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/changelog.html - also do you have any weird time skew issues going on?  ntpd working?

Comment: @mishr : there's nothing in the catalina.out file for the period in question - it gives us no clue. Unless I should be looking at a different log file..?

Comment: @SB: 6.0.36 (I've edited the question). Haven't noticed any problem with timestamps - I have evidence that System.currentTimeInMillis() is returning times correct to within a minute at least.

Comment: I am assuming logging is enabled?

Comment: @mishr : thanks for persisting, I should have been looking in 'localhost.*log' files. I'm not very familiar with tomcat configuration. See the amended question.

Comment: To me it looks like RPC problem. The error message doesn't say much beyond that. You might want to debug(step through) your application to see if you find anything else. Looks like some packages were updated due to which the situation arises. Try to find what packages were updated in the period when the problem started appearing. Keep an eye on any package related to RPC.

Comment: @mishr: I forgot to mention, we use GWT. I've amended the question to make this clear. So a good test would be to try HTTPS on a servlet which bypasses GWT - we do have one.  Thanks!  This should make the problem twice as easy to diagnose.

Comment: @TimCooper In that case, I saw some GWT related threads having the same problem on google groups. Just search for "Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call java.net.SocketTimeoutException" + GWT, and you cannot miss it. As far as I read the threads, there was no solution yet.

Comment: @mishr It looks like you might have diagnosed this problem.  Why don't you create an answer and get the credit for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a long standing issue with RPC calls in a GWT+Tomcat setup. See the following thread for details. Many have reported issue with IE browser, but I assume that is not your case. Few have also reported the problem with Firefox though.

https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4723